# Passing object as a paramter and getting object in return

Tags: java

I have the below code as shown and at last I have shown that how it will be get called when a user will pass the string parameter, he is going to receive the string parameter, my question is can somebody show me how the user will invoke my code by passing an object type as a parameter

below is the interface

```
interface applyBuisnessRule<T> {
    public T execute(String jobCode) throws Exception;
}
```

below is the class

```
class CardvaletImpl<T> implements applyBuisnessRule<T> {
    private static final String Success = null;

    public T execute(String jobCode) throws Exception {
        T result = null;
         // put your logic and populate result here. I believe you are not going to return Success every time as it String
        return result;
    }
}
```

now this code is passing string as a paramater

```
CardvaletImpl<String> cardvaletImpl = new CardvaletImpl<>();
String result = cardvaletImpl.execute("JOBCODE");
```

please advise how can i pass object as aparamter and get object in return as I have done above for the case of string

also please advise how can i make the below class also as generic as this is the context class which is calling my above class

```
public class BuisnessRuleContext {



    private  Object Object = null;
    private applyBuisnessRule buisnessRuleName;

    public void setAbr(applyBuisnessRule abr) {
        this.buisnessRuleName = abr;
    } 

    //use the strategy
      public Object applyBuisnessRule(String jobcode) {

            try {
                Object = buisnessRuleName.execute(jobcode);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return Object;
      }

}
```

Comment: change your function argument to T, 
applyBuisnessRule(T jobcode)

Comment: I think you need to make more of an effort yourself since we are not a code writing service.  I also think you need to ask your instructor for the directions again since I think you missed what you were told to do.  The code above is too incomplete to do anything with (esp. `CardvaletImpl`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want *same* type of object as parameter:

```
interface ApplyBusinessRule<T> {
    public T execute(T jobCode) throws Exception;
}
```

<sup>**Note the corrected interface name.*</sup>

If you want different type of object as parameter:

```
interface ApplyBusinessRule<T, R> {
    public R execute(T jobCode) throws Exception;
}
```

This is similar to how Java 8 defined [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function<T, R> {
    R apply(T t);
}
```

To learn more, read [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).